# Highcharts - chartanimation step by step

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to render charts and animate them step by step?

Right now I got three area-datasets in my chart which I need to animate step by step. Dataset/area 1 shall start and after this is finished, Dataset/area 2 need to start and then 3.
I cannot find an option for that, is this even possible with Highcharts?

Right now the Animation goes from left,bottom to right,up - is there an option for an animation direction? I want to start the animation from the full width (fully expanded on the xAxis) to go upwarts the yAxis.

My Options:

```
var $chart = $('#chart');
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: $chart[0],
        type: 'area',
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        itemMarginBottom: 15,
        borderWidth: 0,
        itemStyle: {
             color: '#9a9a9a',
             fontWeight: '300',
             fontSize: '16px',
             useHTML: true,
         }
    },
    title: false,
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['0', '5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30'],
        lineColor: '#9a9a9a',
        minTickInterval: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'Years',
            style: {
                color: '#000',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#9a9a9a',
                fontSize: '14px'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        tickAmount:5,
        minorTickInterval: 0,
        minorGridLineColor: '#9a9a9a',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        maxPadding: 0.1,
        title: {
            text: 'Eur',
            style: {
                color: '#000',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value:,.0f}',
            style: {
                color: '#9a9a9a',
                fontSize: '14px'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            groupPadding: 0,
            style: {
                color: '#000',
                fontSize: '16px',
                fontWeight: '300'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: '2',
            legendIndex: 2,
            color: '#83bd3f',
            animation: {
                duration: 3000
            },
            data: [1042,
                  2128,
                  3259,
                  4438,
                  5666,
                  6946,
                  7652

              ]
        },
        {
            name: '1',
            legendIndex: 1,
            color: '#24356d',
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            },
            data: [1024,2073,3146,
                4246,
                5372,
                6525,
                7705
            ]

        },
        {
            name: 'Eingezahlte Rate',
            legendIndex: 0,
            color: '#9a9a9a',
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            },
            data: [
                1000,
                2000,
                3000,
                4000,
                5000,
                6000,
                7000
                ]
        }
    ]
});`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [series.afterAnimate](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.events.afterAnimate) event in which you can fire animation for another series.

In your first series set afterAnimate like this:

```
events: {
  afterAnimate: function () {
    this.chart.get('1').update({
      visible: true,
      animation: {
        duration: 2000
      },
      events: {
        afterAnimate: function () {
          this.chart.get('2').update({
            visible: true,
            animation: {
              duration: 3000
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
},
```

For the other series, initially you can disable animation or/and set their visibility to false:

```
series: [{
  name: '2',
  id: '2',
  legendIndex: 2,
  color: '#83bd3f',
  animation: {
    duration: 0
  },
  visible: false,
```

To change the direction of the animation you need to wrap `series.animate`
method and change how the clipping rect is animated.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.area.prototype, 'animate', function(proceed, init) {
    var series = this,
      chart = series.chart,
      clipRect,
      animation = H.animObject(series.options.animation),
      sharedClipKey,
      newH;

    if (init) {
      return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else {

      sharedClipKey = this.sharedClipKey;
      clipRect = chart[sharedClipKey];
      if (clipRect) {
        clipRect.attr({
          y: chart.plotSizeY,
          height: 0,
          width: chart.plotSizeX
        }).animate({
          y: 0,
          height: chart.plotSizeY
        }, animation);
      }
      if (chart[sharedClipKey + 'm']) {
        chart[sharedClipKey + 'm'].attr({
          y: chart.plotSizeY,
          height: 0,
          width: chart.plotSizeX + 99
        }).animate({
          y: 0,
          height: chart.plotSizeY
        }, animation);
      }

      // Delete this function to allow it only once
      series.animate = null;
    }

  });
})(Highcharts)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/0esjvmgL/